# Python framework for desktop app that can be deployed to a webb app later?

Tags: web-apps, video, python, gui

**Primary Concerns**

- The GUI needs to be extensible i.e. there will be text input widget for input, but the user has to be able to click a button that will pop up another text input widget for multiple inputs if so desired.
- An image needs to be displayed that is clickable. i.e. when the image is displayed, the (x,y) coordinates are returned and processing occurs
- Video display with the use of a slider to precisely control frame being looked at would be a big plus. Of course I also want to be able to use the frame the user stops at in conjunction with widgets to operate on the video file
- Cross-platform and easily installed. I want to make this app easily downloadable and usable by people who know nothing of programming.
- Speed is more important than pretty widgets. I need to be able to drop into Fortran to quickly process video files of various formats. Multi-threading and what have you.
- It is hoped that the future of this app will involve a web application and [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/user_guide/server.html) integration for visualizing the data. I have already written a working prototype using [Spyre](https://github.com/adamhajari/spyre) + Heroku and have dabbled around and seen Bokeh work with Django + Webfaction. We were planning on writing javascript to call python functions (that would call Fortran scripts) to make it so that the user can run the app in a browser, but this is sadly more complicated than we initially assumed. We need to process data and have it available so we need a desktop app fast. However, it would be nice if we don't have to rewrite everything after we have a local GUI working and have to make a web app version
- I am looking to learn skills from this project that will make me as employable as possible in 2017. This is an important point and is why I ended up trying Django instead of Flask. So if knowing one desktop GUI is a more marketable skill than another, that may ultimately decide it for me.

**Candidates (will keep updated)**

- wxpython. Main downside is no python 3 support. I don't think this is much of a concern, but it may be a bad idea. Main upside is dabo springboard can be used for sending things to a server
- pyQT. Can use webkit to assist in deploying to a website. My project is open source so $500 fee is not an issue.
- <strike>pyside</strike> ([not as well supported as pyQT](http://neurochannels.blogspot.ca/2014/09/pyside-or-pyqt-for-beginners.html))
- pywebview. Can use webkit to assist in deploying to a website
- <strike>pyGTK</strike> ([poorly supported on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19601167/2734863))
- <strike>Kivy</strike> (Multiple [sources](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-Python-GUI-framework-to-learn-now-that-will-actually-be-used-in-the-future-PyQt-Kivy-PySide-etc) tell me it is more difficult to built widgets with and is more designed with phones involved, not for desktop apps, plus I see no "deploy Kivy app online")
- pajamas. looks very promising and at first glance exactly what we want since the same code for the we app can be used to execute a standalone desktop. I however worry about support (pyQT and wxpython get a lot more love) and what appears to be some pretty [dire](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-Python-GUI-framework-to-learn-now-that-will-actually-be-used-in-the-future-PyQt-Kivy-PySide-etc) and well constructed criticism

Only 4 more to narrow down! Which of these will best meet my requirements or what others are there that should be added to the list?